# How to parse years with BCE/CE suffix in Python?

Tags: python, date

I am trying to present a graph of CE/BCE dates in Python. I tried to use `datetime`, `dateutil` and `astropy` for the graph but it didn't work. 
When I used `datetime` and `astropy` I saw that it did not have support for CE/BCE years. 
With `dateutil` I tried:

```
from dateutil.parser import * 
bc = parse(u'2000BCE')
```

but it had an error:

```
ValueError: Unknown string format
```

How can I present CE/BCE years in python? Is there any library that enables support for BCE/CE years?

The data I'm using is a list of strings and looks like:

```
0 CE
1000 CE
1007 CE
104 BCE
10450 BCE
1050 BCE
1050 BCE
1050 BCE
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! you could start by posting the specific part of the code you already have and that is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "present" and what by "graph"? What exactly did you try (a [mcve] would be helpful) and how did it fail?

Comment: When I used datetime and astropy I saw that it did not have support for BC/BCE years. With dateutil I tried: from dateutil.parser import *

parse(b)
bc = parse(u'2000BC') but it had an error ValueError: Unknown string format

Comment: Thanks for that information. Can you please [edit] it into your question?

Comment: `0` isn't a valid year...

Comment: A rather naive approach assuming that `text` is your lines of dates: `[int(n) * {'CE': 1, 'BCE': -1}[era] for n, era in (line.split() for line in text.splitlines())]`

Comment: @JonClements, why not? It's on the number line...

Comment: @Attie as far as I'm aware - BCE and CE follow the same rules as https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero

Comment: @JonClements interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a packege that supports BCE/CE dates in python so I did the following interpulation:

```
#looks for values containing BCE    
BCE = [s for s in yearsList if "BCE" in s]
#removes BCE string
BCE = [x.strip(' BCE') for x in BCE]
#defines them as integers
BCE = list(map(int, BCE))
#add minus sign to BCE years
BCE = [ -x for x in BCE]

CE = [s for s in yearsList if " CE" in s]
CE = [x.strip(' CE') for x in CE]
CE = list(map(int, CE))

#merges the BCE and the CE integers to one list
mergedlist = BCE + CE

#plot the list
sns.distplot(mergedlist)
plt.xlabel("Year")
```

Comment: very interesting approach.